# Using Headers in xpath to set another header in route?

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have defined a header in my route and want to use the value of the header to determine the other header value.

Example:

```
<route id="use_reference_number">
 <from uri="direct:file_name:use_reference_number">
  <setHeader headerName="FirstNameOfStudent">
    <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//*/Student/StudentName/FirstName/text()</xpath>
  </setHeader>

  <setHeader headerName="NumberOfStudentByThatName">
    <xpath>count(//*/Student[StudentName/FirstName/text() = ${in.header.FirstNameOfStudent}])</xpath>
  </setHeader>
</route>
```

Basically here based on the result from separate x path I want to determine the count of students tags in second one and finally using "NumberOfStudentByThatName" in choice - when to take separate routes. but when I use this expression it returns 0. I think it is not able to resolve the header.

```
<setHeader headerName="NumberOfStudentByThatName">
   <xpath>count(//*/Student[StudentName/FirstName/text() = 'AMAN'])</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

When I use it like above it works perfectly fine , but I don't want to hard code any value instead use what is in the input .

In this case I have two separate xmls and want to use them in cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Camel XPath Component Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/xpath.html) there are special Camel XPath functions like `in:body`, `in:header` etc:
I guess you can make it like:

```
<setHeader headerName="NumberOfStudentByThatName">
  <xpath>count(//*/Student[StudentName/FirstName/text() = in:header("FirstNameOfStudent")])</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

PS. I did not test it and I'm not sure about double quotes in header name - doc page shows me URL encoded values like `&#39;FirstNameOfStudent&#39;`. So, You can figure it out.